# htmlファイル等を作成し、コンソールに命令を書き込みたい

Tags: html, ubuntu, virtualbox, curl

環境　virtualbox
ゲストOS　ubuntu

google-home-notifierのexample.jsを用いて好きな言葉を
googlehomeに話させようとしております。しかし、その際は
コンソール上に

curl -X POST -d "text=話させたい言葉" http://localhost:8091/google-home-notifier

のように書かなければいけません。
コンソール上に一つ一つコマンドを打ち込むのが面倒なので
html等でボタンを作成し、それを押せばブラウザ上からコンソールに上記の命令が
行くようにしたいのですが、そのためにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

他にも良いアイデア等ございましたら、ぜひご教授していただけたら幸いです。

Comment: https://qiita.com/kyota/items/453047f236ca5488027c
 やりたい内容としてはこのようなことですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。そのようなことをしようと考えておりました。